# How to find the second position of N in a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the above as a text what I want is if I type in a letter I should be able to return the position of that letter with the given text for example if I type `T` the result will be `1`, `2` will give `3` however if the text repeats like `E` and `A` I want the position of the second repeating text, eg `E` will give position `7` and `A` position `9`.

```
T  E  2  A  S  H  E  M  A
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

I have tried the following code but for `E` I am getting `2` but I want `7`

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (Col VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES 
('TE2ASHEMA');  -- E = 7 AND A=9

    DECLARE @find varchar(2)
    SET @find ='E'

    SELECT
    Col,
    CHARINDEX(@find,Col) AS Position
    FROM @TBL
```

**Current Output**

```
Col       Position
TE2ASHEMA   2
```

**Expected Output**

```
Col      Position
TE2ASHEMA   7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CHARINDEX` also has a third argument (startposition).

So the following should work:

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (Col VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES 
('TE2ASHEMA');  -- E = 7 AND A=9

DECLARE @find varchar(2)
SET @find ='E'

SELECT
Col,
CHARINDEX(@find,Col, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@find,Col, CHARINDEX(@find,Col)+1) > 0
                          THEN CHARINDEX(@find,Col)+1
                          ELSE 0 END) AS Position
FROM @TBL

-- Output: 7
```

**Note:** The output will always be the first or the second occurence (if existing) even if it occurs three times ore more.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
     DECLARE @TBL TABLE (Col VARCHAR(100))
        INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES 
        ('TE2ASHEMA'); 

            DECLARE @find varchar(2)
            SET @find ='A'


        SELECT col ,  DATALENGTH(col)-CHARINDEX(REVERSE(@find)
        ,REVERSE(col))+1 As Position FROM @TBL



-- Output: 9
```